# Can't exit out of a while loop when using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I know it is not good practice to set a while loop that keeps running until a thread stops running, but I have run out of other ideas. However, even when I resort to this (or something similar to this), I still can't get my program to run properly.

Here is my code:

```
public void phase1() {
    phase1CompoundLabels = new JLabel[numberOfElements];
    okToShowAlternatives = false;

    remove(btnNewButton);
    revalidate();
    repaint();

    while (totalNoOfPhase1Trials > 399) {
        Phase1Trial phase1Trial = new Phase1Trial(numberOfElements, elementColors);

        // this displays a set of images
        displayComplexStimulus(phase1Trial.getComplexStimulus());

        validate();

        // after calling this method the images get removed after two
        // seconds and the okToShowAlternatives variable gets its value
        // changed to true
        removeElementsAfterInterval(2000, phase1CompoundLabels);

        // while(okToShowAlternatives == false){
        // }

        // calling this method displays two images
        // displayAlternatives(phase1Trial.getcorrectImage(),
        // phase1Trial.getincorrectImage(),
        // phase1Trial.getcorrectElementIsOnLeft());


private void removeElementsAfterInterval(int milliseconds, JLabel[] labels) {
    Thread compoundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(milliseconds);
                for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                    remove(labels[i]);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();

                }
                okToShowAlternatives = true;
                System.out.println("OkToShowAlternatives: " + okToShowAlternatives);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

        }

    });
    compoundThread.start();
}
```

With the while loop (the one with the OkToShowAlternatives in the condition) and the displayAlternatives() method call commented out, as shown, the program up to that point works fine, as the set of images display for two seconds and then get removed from the jpanel. However, when I include the while loop, the program stops displaying the set of images, and I can't even close the jframe. It is completely unresponsive.

However when I included a print statement to see if the value of OkToShowElements variable changes to true, it does. So, shouldn't the condition of the while loop no longer be satisfied and therefore exit out of the while loop and continue onto the next part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to interact with Swing components from a different thread. Because Swing is designed single-threaded, you can get all kinds of race conditions and memory visibility problems if you do any interaction with the component tree in Swing from a different thread than the UI thread.

Use Swing Timers to execute code on the Swing UI thread, after a specified delay:

```
ActionListener executeThisAfterDelay = ...;
Timer timer = new Timer(speed, executeThisAfterDelay);
timer.setInitialDelay(pause);
timer.start();
```

For further reference, see the [How To Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) Java tutorial on Oracle's website.

Comment: So are you saying that everything has to be in the same thread if i am changing components in a jpanel? I'm confused, because wouldnt that mean that you could never use multithreading when using a gui?

Comment: what Erwin said is do not interact with swing components in another thread.  You can still make use of threads to do lots of other things, just not interacting directly with gui components

Comment: @lb91 Adrian is right. You can use multiple threads, but they cannot interact with Swing directly. But they can use another method, `EventQueue.invokeLater` to schedule a piece of code to run on the UI thread later. If necessary, another thread can even do `EventQueue.invokeAndWait` to do something on the UI thread right now, but you should try to avoid that latter method to get the best multi-threaded performance.